# How do I remove spaces between words when the words are in the same cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have one cell. It contains First Last name. What's the formula to remove the space between First Last so the result is firstlast?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with SUBSTITUTE:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")
```

If you need it in lower case, use LOWER, or PROPER only for the first letter in capitals:

```
=LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))
=PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

or try:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1; " "; )
```